# How to delete unnecessary outer folder in github

Tags: git, react-native, github

My folder structure looks like this:

1.Outer folder
1.1 Inner Folder
1.1.1 .....Main files

Now the outer folder is a git folder that we get after creating a new repo and cloning it while the inner folder is the folder that you get when creating a new react native app. Essentially I should have created the RN app before and then add it to my Github. Now the problem is I have this unnecessary outer folder that does nothing so I want to remove it. What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: You can put the folder name in gitignore file

Comment: `git mv 'outer folder/inner folder' 'inner folder'`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply move the content of the inner folder at the root of the repository:

```sh
git mv innerfolder/* .
rmdir innerfolder
git commit --message "move folders one level up"
```

If you want to change the whole history to look like it was like this from the beginning, you can use `git filter-branch` with the option `--subdirectory-filter` (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#Remap_to_ancestor). Or the more modern `git filter-repo` with the same option (https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html)

Comment: this is giving an error `fatal: bad source, source=chatApp/*, destination=*`

Comment: Can you show the exact command you launch?

Comment: Did you already commit the inner folder? If not, simple `mv` instead of `git mv`

Comment: Yes I have already made a few commits. This is the command that I ran `git mv chatApp/* .` where "chatApp" is the inner folder containing all the important files.

Comment: What terminal are you using? (You may encounter this kind of issue: https://superuser.com/questions/1050326/git-mv-returns-bad-source-in-powershell)